# Flatpak: total used space on harddisk?

Tags: storage, flatpak

can the totally used storage space on harddisk (ubuntu 20.04) used by all flatpak files be
shown by using this command?

```
du -hc /var/lib/flatpak/*
```

If not, what would be an  appropriate command?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

```
du -hs /var/lib/flatpak/*
```

or even

```
du -hs /var/lib/flatpak
```

instead. Where

- `-h`, `--human-readable`

  > print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
- `-s`, `--summarize`

  > display only a total for each argument

See `man du` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/du.1.html) for details.

---

Also please note that `flatpak list --show-details` will show sizes of applications in more user-friendly form.